# 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation' during data binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I get the following error *'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'*

This is my code behind

```
ContactModel ConversationPartner;
        
        public MessagesPage(ContactModel input)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ConversationsList = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();
            ConversationPartner = input;
           ...


          }
           ...
 public string FirstContactName
        {
            get { return ConversationPartner.contactName[0]; }
        }

        public string SecondContactId
        {
            get { return ConversationPartner.contactID[1]; }
        }

        public string SecondContactName
        {
            get { return ConversationPartner.contactName[1]; }
        }
```

And here's my XAML, specifically where I'm trying to bind FirstContactName, SecondContactId, and SecondContactName

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <x:Reference Name="messagesPage" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

...

 <Label Text="{Binding FirstContactName}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding SecondContactId, Converter={StaticResource isViewerConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Text"  Value="{Binding SecondContactName}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>
                    </Label>
```

Comment: Where you binding data source to contentpage? just using `<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <x:Reference Name="messagesPage" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>`,please take a look [Data Bindings to mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#interactive-mvvm) to modify your binging.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do also set property for this field because data-binding work both ways
or also you can change the data - binding way to be one way.

good luck!!

Comment: How do I go about inserting return ConversationPartner.contactName[1]; if it's initially in the setter?

Comment: o change the binding to be one way and you don't must to add set in this property. 
EDIT:
 to change the data binding way just change Text="{Binding FirstContactName}" to Text="{Binding Path =FirstContactName, Mode=OneWay}"